# Creating eclipse project from old project

Tags: eclipse, svn, project

I have an old eclipse java project which is stored in SVN. I wish to create a new one based on the old one but without the SVN files. I'll be doing some experimental changes to it and I want to have the old one as backup basically. Anyone can give advice on how to do this?  Thanks

FYI: This has been posted in Javaranch as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a number of options:

1. Don't do a check-out (which creates the metadata files, allowing for changes to be easily and later committed), but an export instead.  From the "SVN Repositories" view in Eclipse, right-click the project folder, then click "Export...".
2. Just check-out a 2nd copy of the project from SVN, naming it with a different project name in the workspace to keep it distinct.  Just refrain from checking-in any changes back to the SVN repository.
3. Copy the project as usual, and simply delete the SVN metadata files.
4. Same as #3, but let Eclipse do this for you - using Team / Disconnect.